# Python modules/libraries work in iPython but not in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, matplotlib

I am using:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))

and eclipse gives the following error: undefined variable Spectral.

Surprisingly, this works on iPython (I am on ubuntu 14.04).

I have had same issue with other modules/libraries. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You have to make sure that eclipse uses the same python interpreter as the one you use in your shell.

Comment: Thanks. I did that by right click on the project->PyDev-Interpretor and it is set on Defult. Id there a better way to verify that?